# как добавить всем дочерним элементам id (.find может)

Tags: jquery

Как добавить каждому дочернем элементам id и записать это айди в массив? ЧТо-то типа внутри div, такого плана $('#'+newiddx+'*').children().attr('id')

Comment: конкретизируйте вопрос. каким дочерним, вряд ли же вы пишите про все элементы в документе?

Comment: внутри div, такого плана $('#'+newiddx+'*').children().attr('id')

Comment: какой именно id ты хочешь добавить? Приведи пример разметки и результат, который ты хочешь получить

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно вас понял

```js
var arrowId = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <  $('#parent>*').length + 1; i++) {
        var newId = 'block-'+i;
        $('#parent>*:nth-child('+i+')').attr('id', newId);
        arrowId.push(newId);
    }
  console.log(arrowId)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <span>1</span>
    <div>2</div>
    <span>3</span>
    <div>4</div>
    <span>5</span>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вроде как оно, сейчас попробую и отпишусь. Большое спасибо)

Comment: Получается он почему то не до конца списка элементов доходит

Comment: Покажите свой код, так трудно судить.

Comment: вроде вот это сработало 
var arrowId = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <  $('#'+newiddx).children().length+1; i++) {
        var newId = newiddx+'_'+i;
        $('#'+newiddx+'>*:nth-child('+i+')').attr('id', newId);
        arrowId.push(newId);
    }
  console.log(arrowId);

Comment: даже в том примере что выше выложили тоже не до конца делает перебор элементом, присмотритесь вывод ответа при нажатии выполнить

Comment: Да поправил в своем примере.

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже так сделал поставил +1). Вы очень выручили, искал в гугл ответ не нашел, решил попросить помощи на форуме. Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: И счетчик в цилке от 1 поставьте , а то лишний элемент, будет в массиве.

Answer (score 0):

более простой вариант для верстки из соседнего ответа.

```js
var ids = $("#parent *").map(function(idx){
              const id = 'id-' + idx;
              $(this).attr('id', id);   
              return id;
          }).get();
          
console.log(ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <span>1</span>
    <div>2</div>
    <span>3</span>
    <div>4</div>
    <span>5</span>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, если не сложно, посоветуйте пожалуйста литературу по jquery и js